# Codeigniter not woking on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i have a fresh copy of CodeIgniter configured on my local server and works fine. but when i upload in http://subdomain.mydomain.com it shows an error.

> ```
> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.
> ```

Is there a problem with my hosting provider or i can fix this using a .htacess file?

i have no clue what i am dealing with.
any help is appreciated.

> ```
> error_log
> [28-Apr-2015 19:53:56 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: >     Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/timezonedb.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/timezonedb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
> ```

Thanks

Comment: find more information on the web server error log and post it here.

Comment: can you display yor routing file?

Answer (score 0):

Note : can run in local web server not always success run in real server.
In codeigniter 3 you must case sensitive code and using Capital Each Word in every class like this.

HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

CONFIG

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://heloo.cmsapp.com/';
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

ROUTING

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = "Page_controller/home";
$route['page/contact'] = "Page_controller/contact";
```

CONTROLLER

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function home() {
        //load your home page
    }

    public function contact() {
        //load your contact page
    }

}
```

Read this documet :
[www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html)